# Highlight the URL/omnibox text on new tab load (Chrome)

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, omnibox

How do I programatically select the URL text once the new tab has loaded?

This is the code for redirect.js

```
/*global chrome,document,window */
(function init() {
    "use strict";
    chrome.storage.local.get(["url","tab.selected"], function (items) {
        var url = items.url;
        if(url) {
            var selected = items["tab.selected"] === undefined ? true : (items["tab.selected"] == "true");
            chrome.tabs.update({
                "url": url,
                "selected": selected
            });
        } else {
            angular.resumeBootstrap();
        }
    });
}());
```

Soon as the page at "url" is loaded, I want it to automatically highlight the URL/omnibox text so the user can start typing without pressing Ctrl+A.

Thank you

**EDIT:** The focus is on the omnibox, but the text already present is not highlighted. I want it so that it is highlighted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this using a Workaround.

Using [Autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com), I coded a simple script which:

1. monitors for new windows.
2. When a new window is detected, it checks the name of the window to see if it is "chrome://..." (I add the '...' because using users can choose what to display on the new tab page. I have chrome://apps/ as my new tab page.
3. Upon discovering the new window was chrome://..., it sends the Ctrl+A keystroke which selects the entire text in the omnibox.

Simple. Elegant :P

Here is the code, modify as you wish (you will need Autohotkey_L to execute the code. Alternatively, you can turn it into an .exe for compatibility. See documentation on link above.

```
#Persistent
#SingleInstance, Force
#NoTrayIcon
SetBatchLines, -1
SetTitleMatchMode, 2
SetWinDelay, -1

/** Enter the name of the Chrome new tab page here, for me it is "Apps - Google Chrome" */

ChromeTab := "Apps - Google Chrome"

Gui +LastFound
hWnd := WinExist()

DllCall( "RegisterShellHookWindow", UInt,hWnd )
MsgNum := DllCall( "RegisterWindowMessage", Str,"SHELLHOOK" )
OnMessage( MsgNum, "ShellMessage" )
Return

ShellMessage( wParam,lParam ) {
    Global Last
    if (wParam = 16 && Last = 6) {
        WinGetActiveTitle, T
        if (T = ChromeTab) {
            SendInput, {Control Down}l{Control Up}
        }
    }
    Last := wParam
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It might be possible to add a keypress such as F6 to highlight it for you.

For pressing enter this works, not sure if the VK_ is required but changed ENTER to F6 might work.

`Robot r = new Robot();
r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);`